# Authentication Internet Explorer

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, authentication

The problem is that I am using this for the URL:

```
$params = array(
  scope => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  redirect_uri => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome and the page loads inside Facebook.  The problem comes with Internet Explorer and it breaks out of Facebook and sends them to www.myapp.com instead.

I tried changing www.myapp.com to the Facebook page but all this does is mess up the authentication.

Comment: did you tried to leave out the redirect_uri, it should use your current url automaticly